# Dotnet OpenId Connect change scopes at runtime

Tags: .net-core, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using keycloak together with my dotnet application to handle authentication - with Keycloak 18 I want to use dynamic scopes, and by that i also need to be able to change my scope values based on the current user and actions at runtime.

The use case is that a user by selecting some options add additional scopes that needs to be evaluated by keycloak at runtime, imagine that a user selects an app and a dynamic scope named `app` changes based on this `app:<APP_ID>` and then keycloak needs to evaluated the new scope, the user can at any time change this scope by interacting with the UI.

Currently my startup configures the authentication in `AddOpenIdConnect` with a number of default scopes, but i can't figure out how to dynamically change these scopes at runtime for the individual users.

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are values that are fixed at design time, representing an area of data and operations allowed on that data. An example might be `products_read`, which is the only thing your app needs to know about when managing user logins.

Claims are used when dynamic behaviour is needed. The above scope might be composed of two claims for `user_type` and `subscription_level`. These claims can be assigned different values for different users at the time of token issuance. Keycloak could collect these values via an API call or database lookup.

The end result is that the scope and both claims are issued to access tokens, and available to the backend for authorization purposes. The [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) article has further info on this design pattern.

Comment: I am trying to enable some dynamic tenant support, so the user can change tenant / app and thereby request the claims for a given app (scope) - apps are created dynamically and the claims are created by an external system that needs the app i to resolve the claims - and for that i want to use dynamic scope in Keycloak and a custom mapper to read and resolve the claims based on the scope id value

Comment: Could be something like the prefix scopes https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/#prefix-scopes

Comment: I would probably prefer just adding a tenant ID array claim to access tokens. Then using other scopes in a standard way to control access to the type of app. Prefix scopes have more of a per-transaction based usage, one example being Open Banking  and [Lodging Intent](https://curity.io/resources/learn/consentors-in-financial-grade/).